# Strange crash with glTexSubImage2D and Java's IntBuffer

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I have an Android app that has created a Texture using glTexImage2D, so I can edit it later using glTexSubImage2D:

```
private void buildTexture() 
{
    if(canvasTexture[0] != -1)
    {
        GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, canvasTexture, 0);
        canvasTexture[0] = -1;
    }
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, canvasTexture, 0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, canvasTexture[0]);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST); 
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_NEAREST);
    GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, canvasDims.x(), canvasDims.y(), 0, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvasBuffer);
}
```

The dimensions are 128x64 and canvasBuffer was initialized as follows:

```
canvasBuffer = IntBuffer.allocate(canvasDims.x()*canvasDims.y());
```

Basically I want to keep an IntBuffer in native memory that holds the entire image, and update it when needed and where needed.

Here is where the problem starts. I am trying to update a section of the texture, giving it the matching section in my buffer:

```
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, canvasTexture[0]);
    canvasBuffer.position(1); //anything but 0 makes it crash
    GLES20.glTexSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, canvasBuffer);
    canvasBuffer.position(0);
```

The call to glTexSubImage2D causes a crash (SIGSEGV - invalid mem access), if and only if the position is set to anything but 0 in the prev. line.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: What is canvasDims? Have you checked that the functions x() and y() return the correct values?

Comment: yes, they return 128 and 64 respectively. The problem is that with position set to 0 I can write thru the whole 8192 integers in the buffer.
When position is not 0, lets say 1, glTexSubImage2D crashes no matter the parameters.

Comment: Did you found a solution? I'm experiencing same problem